# @data.nextlink is not present in the securit graph API when trying t pull last set of data

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-api-apps

While using security graph api in azure, when i reach the last set of data in the payload @data.nextlink is missing,so that i'm unable to fetch the next set of data?

Answer (score 0):

I read the `Graph api` and `Security Graph api` carefully, and I found that when the current page data is fully loaded, there should be no `@odata.nextlink` parameter.

***When you see my test results, I think this api design may need to be improved, when `$top` is equal to odata count.***

Because all the data has been loaded, there is no next page of data you mentioned.

## Sample

**Query this api**

**I know that this api will return 63 data after access.**

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/security/secureScores?$top=63&$count=true`

**Result**

[image]

Query `@odata.nextLink`.

[image]

When `$top=63`, although there is no data on the next page, there will still be the `@odata.nextLink` parameter.

When `$top=64`, we will see that the `@odata.nextLink` parameter is gone.

[image]